# Method for simple decryption, hard encryption

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, serial-number

I'm looking for something like an inverse RSA algorithm. Normally, e.g. in RSA, a public key is used to encrypt the text, but it's virtually impossible to decrypt the text without the private key. What I'm looking for is a method that can decrypt a text using a public key easily, but for encrypting the text and reaching the same ciphertext, a private and a public key should be needed. Is there such a method at all?

My first attempt was to use the RSA crypto service that's build into .NETs system.security.cryptography and just decrypt my plain text (instead of decrypting it). However, that doesn't work as the implementation (or the method, haven't looked at it in that detail) is not able to decrypt arbitrary text, even if the string length is ok. Afterwards I would have encrypted the cipher text to reach the plain text again, but as said, already the first step doesn't work.

The background is the following: From some known information, I want to be able to generate a string which serves as serial number for a program. That should involve some kind of key that I want to store only in the number generator but not in the program that I deploy. The program itself should only be able to decrypt the number and extract the information from the text. The reason for using that kind of asymmetric cipher is that even if the program got cracked, nobody should ever know the key that is used to generate the serial numbers.

Comment: This is called a *digital signature* if I'm not mistaken – anyone can check if the signature is valid, but you can only sign messages if you have the private key.

Comment: It's possible with a modified implementation of the RSA library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38739/RSA-Private-Key-Encryption

Comment: Note that if your program is "cracked" they will just patch the program to just change your validation code to `bool ValidSerial(String serial) { return true; }`. What you are talking about is protecting yourself from a keygen being created, which is a good goal to have, but it wont protect against "cracks".

Comment: @Scott: sure, that was my intention.

Comment: @ntoskrnl: No, it's not a digital signature. There is a slight difference: A digital signature comes together with a plain text which is hashed and then encrypted. From the signature alone, it is not possible to reproduce the plain text. In my case, there is only a cipher text which is decrypted to the original text. No plain text, no hashing.

Comment: But there's no point in a ciphertext which anyone can decrypt (using a public key). Perhaps you could generate random data and sign that – the application verifies the signature to validate the product key.